# Set default selected value in Select2 fetching data from ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery-select2

I filter a list of result using some input fields and this one:

```
$("#idCustomer").select2({
      allowClear: true,
      placeholder: "Filter",
      ajax: {
        url: 'ajax/search_customers.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        type: "GET",
        processResults: function (data) {
            return {
                results: $.map(data, function (item) {
                    return {
                        text: item.Name,
                        id: item.ID
                    }
                })
            };
        }
      }
    });
```

It works great, but after submit the form, I'd like to fill the inputs with filter i've been applied. Ok for all others inputs:

For example:

```
<input id="minRange" name="minRange" value="<?php echo $minRange; ?>">
```

My page.php

```
if ( isset($_POST) ) {
    $minRange = $_POST['minRange'];
    $idCustomer = $_POST['idCustomer'];
    ...
}
```

But i don't know how to autofill Select2 with the search i've used. For example if i write "DEM" my Select2 suggest me "DEMO CUSTOMER" (with ID = 4). I select this, submit the form, and after reload the page, Select2 `idCustomer` still empty.
I'd like to inizialize it using id = 4 passed to the form for the search.

I've tried to append `$("#idCustomer").val(<?php echo $idCustomer; ?>).trigger("change");`

but it doesn't work.

I'm using latest 4.1 version of the plugin

Answer (score 0):

you have to mention select for autocomplete

//HTML

//JS

```
$("#idCustomer").select2({
  allowClear: true,
  placeholder: "Filter",
  ajax: {
    url: 'ajax/search_customers.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    type: "GET",
    processResults: function (data) {
        return {
            results: $.map(data, function (item) {
                return {
                    text: item.Name,
                    id: item.ID
                }
            })
        };
    }
  },
  minLength: 2,
  select: function(event, ui) {

    var Name = ui.item.Name;
    $("#minRange").val(Name);
  }
})
```

;

Answer (score 0):

Solved with:

```
<select id="idCustomer" name="idCustomer" class="form-control">
                    <?php if ( $idCustomer != "" ) { ?><option value="<?php echo $idCustomer; ?>"><?php echo get_info_by_id($idCustomer)['Name']; ?></option><?php } ?>
</select>
```

Select2 does the rest!